# Javascript button color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have form with 2 radio buttons: Approve and Deny. The task is: if 'Approve' button clicked 'Deny' button needs to have default styling and 'Approve' button needs to become green (.btn-success). if 'Deny' button clicked, 'Approve' button needs to have default styling and 'Deny' button needs to become red(.btn-danger)

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons" id="CategoryInputs">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
     <input id="approve" name="status" required="" type="radio" value="category 1" />APPROVE
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
     <input id="deny" name="status" required="" type="radio" value="category 2" />DENY
  </label>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  // highlight selected category
  $("#CategoryInputs input:radio").change(function(){
    $("#approve").parent().removeClass("btn-success");
    $("#approve").parent().addClass("btn-default");
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(this).parent().removeClass("btn-default");
      $(this).parent().addClass("btn-success");
    }else{
      $(this).parent().removeClass("btn-success");
      $(this).parent().addClass("btn-default");
    }

    $("#deny").parent().removeClass("btn-danger");
    $("#deny").parent().addClass("btn-default");
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(this).parent().removeClass("btn-default");
      $(this).parent().addClass("btn-danger");
    }else{
      $(this).parent().removeClass("btn-danger");
      $(this).parent().addClass("btn-default");
    }
  });
  // end highlight
});
```

I am obviously doing something wrong. because both buttons are just getting red :(

Comment: Might want to look at [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying and removing at the same time the classes. Take a look at this example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // highlight selected category
  $("#CategoryInputs input:radio").change(function(){
    $("#approve, #deny").parent().removeClass("btn-success btn-danger").addClass("btn-default");    
    
    if($(this).is(":checked") && this.id == "approve"){
      $(this).parent().removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
    }else{
      $(this).parent().removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-danger");
    }    
    
  });
  // end highlight
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons" id="CategoryInputs">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
     <input id="approve" name="status" required="" type="radio" value="category 1" />APPROVE
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
     <input id="deny" name="status" required="" type="radio" value="category 2" />DENY
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similarly problem, when I tried to toggle classes. Now I am using [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/)

It looks like you are using Bootstrap. I recommend you to use the plugin. It makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed your code, in your example you were applying the classes at the same time.

```
$("#CategoryInputs input:radio").change(function(){
    $("#approve").parent().removeClass("btn-success").parent().addClass("btn-default");
    $("#deny").parent().removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-default");

    if($('#approve').is(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
    }else {
        $("#deny").parent().removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-danger");
    }
});
```